# Symfony 2.3 Join tables using composite keys

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

have a element class with composite keys.
When I run php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
I get the following error

> The join columns of the association 'parentElement' have to match to
>   ALL identifier columns of the target entity
>   'AgRecord\AppBundle\Entity\Element', however 'id, parent_uuid' are
>   missing.

What am I missing or how do I correctly describe the relationship?

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Elements
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="elements",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"uuid", "id", "parent_uuid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", columnDefinition="INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;   

    /**
     * @var guid
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @var guid
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_uuid", type="string")
     */
    private $parentUUID;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Element", inversedBy="childElements")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uuid", referencedColumnName="parent_uuid")
    */
    private $parentElement;


    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Element", mappedBy="parentElement")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uuid", referencedColumnName="element_uuid")
    */
    private $childElements;

}
```

Comment: Is this your minimum viable code example? Please clean up the code clutter which is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst sorry, cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stupid I had all the mappings mixed up...

I solved my issue kind of.

First I decided to just remove id and have uuid, which meant i didnt need a composite key.

Then needed to remove stupidly placed @Id off of all non primary fields

Then removed the $parentUUID.
I was doing it the wrong way and didn't understand the mapping, and using an extra reference when it wasn't needed.

Then removed the joined annotation from the child elements and made sure to have the inversedby correctly set on the parent.

The name on the parent join annotation needs to be the name of the class member associated.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Elements
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="elements")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element
{

    private $id;   

    /**
     * @var guid
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Element", inversedBy="childElements")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentElement", referencedColumnName="uuid")
    */
    private $parentElement;


    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Element", mappedBy="parentElement")
    */
    private $childElements;

}
```